# How to show selected feature top in map?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology

As shown in the piucture, there is a bunch of multilines in one layer. I selected one feature from the attribute table and wanted to look at its contour.
[image]

But the contour is overlapped by other features in this layer.
[image]

I'm looking for an option to bring the selected feature to the top in the upper picture. I'm using QGIS 3.10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `Rule-based` symbology. Add new rule with `is_selected()` filter.

[image]

Then change the symbol rendering order with `Symbol Levels...`. Set the highest value on your symbol with `is_selected()` filter.

[image]

This resutls to:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I figured that the solution had something to do with filters/rule based styling. I especially posted that question as open as possible to get all kinds approaches. I was hoping for something like a hidden settings feature or system variable :)

Answer (score 5):

In the **Symbology** panel -> **Layer Rendering** section, enable *Control feature rendering order*. Add an expression with the value `is_selected()`, ensuring it is set to Ascending.

[image]

Comment: That's basically the same answer as the one posted and accepted two and a half year before!

Comment: Disagree, it is more simple and allows you to keep existing symbology

Comment: Anyone know how to do this for all layers by default? Or by default when layer is loaded?